# How do I unlock more Break types?

Tags: prinny-2

I noticed the Tutorial guy (sitting on the pumpkin) has an option to let you change break type. It's greyed out. I've been getting Lucky Dolls but haven't unlocked a new Break type yet. I haven't yet beaten the game (I'm replaying to unlock all normal stages/times).

How do I unlock more Break types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of [the FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/psp/977827-prinny-2-dawn-of-operation-panties-dood/faqs/59547) for Break Mode yielded this information:

> ### TYPES OF BREAK MODE
>
> You can switch the break mode type from the Tutorial NPC's menu.
>
> ## STANDARD BREAK
>
> Default Break mode. When you enter Break mode, a burst of lightning
>   goes  down on the Prinny. This effect actually causes massive damage
>   to nearby enemies as well as stage objects, so it could be both useful
>   and dangerous at certain times. It's especially dangerous if you
>   activate Break mode while standing on breakable platforms. Standard
>   Break mode doubles your attack damage, making rapid attacks MUCH more
>   potent against enemies.
>
> ## CLASSIC BREAK
>
> This is the first game's combo gauge function. You don't enter Break
>   mode, (and thus have no access to Break mode attacks) instead you are
>   rewarded with sweets and scarfs/diapers when you fill up the gauge.
>
> **Classic Break is unlocked by beating the game once.**
>
> ## SCORE BREAK
>
> A special Break mode that focuses on score bonuses. When you enter
>   Score Break, any and all sources of Score will be multiplied by 4.
>   Sweets, enemies, bosses, you name it. There are some problematic
>   disadvantages to Score Break:
>
> - No blue aura on ANY move
> - No Prinny Cyclone (Hero Prinny)
> - Instead of bouncing off a wall when you bump into them during a dash or dash jump, Prinny instantly explodes and dies.
> - No damage increase during break mode
>
> **Score Break is unlocked as a reward for collecting 52 Lucky Dolls.**

Comment: Oh, crap, those aren't very useful at all...

Comment: No. No, they aren't. But they're fun, I'm sure. Dying as soon as you bump into something during a dash sounds like *fun*.

Comment: As a side note, Score Break means you die every time you bump into something even if you have a scarf/diaper left, even when you're not IN break. The score boost is otherwise pretty nice for earning titles...